# Create motorola s-record with fixed size length

Tags: c++, c, linker, embedded, objcopy

Because I have to use a third-party bootloader which cannot handle varying lengths of lines in an SREC file, I need a way to instrument `objcopy` to create a SREC file, where every `S1` line has the same lengths (if no info from ELF file is provided, it should be filled with `FF`).

We can assume that the address increments are consistent, so we do not jump higher in addresses than our specified line length. So we do not need to create in-between lines with all `FF` e.g.

I found out about `--srec-len` but this only sets the maximum length size.
I would need something that sets a fixed length size, is there something I can use?

A possible solution would be also to transform the earlier generated SREC file from objcopy with a (third-party) tool

Comment: Since you've tagged it [c] and [c++], it's worth mentioning that you could create your own tool. It sounds like a reasonably simple task to convert an SREC file with varying lengths into an SREC file with fixed lengths.

Comment: @user253751 I did it already "by hand" and I thought about writing a small python script and if until next week I find now better solution, I am going to do this. But I thougt maybe there are possible other users who came across the same problem

Comment: If you come from automotive world you can use the Vector HexView or WindRiver ddump as an alternative 3rd party, both can be used to generate SREC with fixed length.

Comment: Probably worth seeing if there's some combination of options to srec_cat which could do this, either by itself or with modifications to fill out the end of a line.  Going through an intermediate flat binary stage could also be an option - start with a block of "erased", `dd` a partial binary over it, re-encode to hex.

Comment: Writing such a program yourself is indeed not rocket science. Read the file and write a new one simultaneously. Store all data in RAM until you have enough to write a fixed length to the new file. Recalculate address and checksum. Repeat until done. Leave S0 and S9 as they were. Couple of hours of work, at most.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the srec_cat utility to do this. Following is an example command.

"srec_cat long.srec −o short.s19 −line-length=46"